# jQuery/js - Clearing multiselect selections on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I remove the dropdown selections after my function stores into local storage. Please see my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3u7Xj/139/

I already have this for the other elements:

```
 var $form = $("#formID");

 $form.find('input:text, input:password, input:file, select, textarea').val('');
 $form.find('input:radio, input:checkbox')
    .removeAttr('checked').removeAttr('selected');
```

Comment: You want to remove the selection or remove the select element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add:

```
$form.find(".multiselect").multiselect('uncheckAll');
```

I updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3u7Xj/140/

Comment: Note that is `uncheckAll`, not `uncheckall`.